# How to provide advanced window manager amenities to an undecorated Stage in JavaFX 2?

Tags: java, javafx-2, custom-component, window-managers

For reasons of aesthetics and usability, my program uses an undecorated `Stage`.
I have implemented the core functions - minimize, maximize, close, resize and drag are all present.

Now, I discovered that the program is lacking some advanced features that I took for given:
On a Windows XP system, clicking the program's entry in the taskbar no longer minimizes it.
On a KDE system, dragging does not allow any part of the `Stage` to leave the screen.

Each feature is present on the respective other system; both work on each system when the stage is decorated.

I would like to whether I can somehow re-create this behaviour in my program without reverting to a decorated stage. The `Stage` API does not seem to offer anything helpful.

Comment: KDE system? Is JavaFX working on Linux?

Comment: Absolutely. The Big 3 are all supported.

Comment: Try to update to latest version of JavaFX to see if something changes.

Answer (score 0):

A hack to get this to work might be to create a decorated stage as the parent of your undecorated stage.  Position the decorated stage so that it is hidden behind the undecorated stage.  Functionality like clicking on the program's entry in the taskbar should work (and hopefully the hacked arrangement won't cause other insurmountable issues).  You'll need listeners on visible and hidden states of your windows and tracking of their size so that you can correctly maintain the relationships between the top undecorated window and the hidden decorated window.  You can request official APIs which more directly provide the functionality you are seeking at http://javafx-jira.kenai.com